# Python operators of unequality

Tags: python-3.6

i have a code, not written by me . I am learning python and at very basics

codes are below:

```
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"

print("Wait there are not 10 things in that list. Let's fix that.")

stuff = ten_things.split(' ')
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee",
"Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]

while len(stuff) != 10:

    next_one = more_stuff.pop()
    print("Adding: ", next_one)
    stuff.append(next_one)
    print(f"There are {len(stuff)} items now.")

print("There we go: ", stuff)

print("Let's do some things with stuff.")

print(stuff[1])
print(stuff[-1]) # whoa! fancy
print(stuff.pop())
print(' '.join(stuff)) # what? cool!
print('#'.join(stuff[3:5])) # super stellar!
```

my question is we use while len(stuff) !=10 but it runs till 10 only, it should skip 10 and go ahead until it pops the whole list but why it runs till 10? there are 11,12,13 and 14 which are also not equal to 10.It should also include them.

ideally, it should be while len(stuff) => 10: but we used != which is also not equal

can anyone help me?

Comment: You're trying to read code you don't understand the purpose for. Of course you're having trouble.

Comment: i understand the purpose, my question is on notequality operator (!=), it should skip 10 and go ahead...because it is not equal to 10

Comment: The relation is critical for the purpose of the code.

Comment: but please if can teach the criticality of this?

Comment: Sure. The code appends items **while** there aren't 10 of them.

Comment: no no..i want to what does unequality signs means? if i say while true : 1 !=2, it means 1 is also not equal to 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,.......and so on?

Comment: You're confusing the condition for the loop.

Comment: This is the thing i wish to know, just for knowledge